# Why Lucene locks the entire Directory? why not just lock individual lucene files?

Tags: java, lucene, directory, locking

I am writing a custom lucenene Directory implementation and was wondering why did the IndexWriter lock the entire Directory instance instead of locking file by file.

I am not much familiar with Lucene internals yet but with what i read of it so far, i was thinking to limit the locking to per instance of each 'luce index file type' in order to support concurrent indexing by multiple indexers

I am sure if this is so simple many others would have done it by now; so wondering why is it not done this way, and why the entire directory is locked...

Could someone explain the reasons why it is done so, and reasons why not do what i suggested?

Thanks,
Samba

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding about [Lucene file format](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/fileformats.html#file-names) is oversimplified.

Not only Lucene doesn't use a single file per term like you suggested, but it also stores a lot of other important information - term vectors, frequencies, pointers and so on. Also, it has to store deleted files and perform merges (and this happens behind the scenes!) - I can assure you the overall complexity is quite high. On top of that, Lucene provides [transactional support and implements all ACID properties](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/03/transactional-lucene.html). None of this would be easily possible (or even possible at all) having multiple concurrent writers. In other words, Lucene is geared towards CA [in CAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

The good thing is that since version 4, you can [plug your own format](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/07/building-new-lucene-postings-format.html), so feel free to experiment and suggest a better alternative.

Comment: Hi Mindas,

I was suggesting to lock _n.fdt file while updating field data for the nth segment, similarly locking _n.fdx while upadting field index for nth segment, etc. 

Or if this does not work, we may lock all lucene format files for a particular segment; or may be we lock a particular lucene format file for all segments.

I would like to know disadvantages of each of these approaches or clear NO if none works safely.

Comment: For your knowledge, field data is never updated - each time you want to update indexed document, writer deletes old document and adds it again with the changed field(s). So there is no locking on this operation in particular; segment file names are never reused but always incremented (alpha-numeric base 36 form). File write.lock only ensures one `IndexWriter` can use the directory at the time, but it doesn't mean that `IndexWriter` only allows a single thread to write.

Comment: i was looking at indexing from multiple machines into a common index; hence rose the question of relaxing the locking mechanism from directory specific to file specific or format specific.

Comment: infact, i am expecting that when we use the compound file format, it would be much easier to lock each .cfs file (for each segment) instead of the entire directory; and thus gain better concurrrent (from multiple machines) performance while indexing

Comment: Ok, simple use case. One writer adds a document and decides it's time to merge the segments and starts (possibly lengthy) merge process. While this is happening, how would you imagine another writer adding another document concurrently?

Comment: the Writer deciding to merge should first acquire lock on all the  segment(s) it wanted to merge; and thus any other writers wishing to write to those segmens will get blocked until the merged segment is released by the merging writer. these short periods of locking is acceptable but not being able to index from multiple writers(systems) looks like a serious limitation for scalability. I do not want to subindex (thus spit the index into multiple directories) because that would mean i need to run multiple queries on each subindex to find the best n out of the total results